# Finding spatial coordinates in geo-tagged image

Tags: jpg

I have a geo-tagged jpg. I know image resolution, GPS location and height, even some angles.

How can I calculate lat/lon for pixel, bounding box, etc from this data?

Can someone give me a hint, maybe formula for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "geo-tagged"? Is it just some photo you took with oblique angle, or is it georectified / orthorectified with appropriate metadata? What does `gdalinfo` show for the image?